# How to compare two values in two collections - pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have two collections.
For example;

```json
collection1: 
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("6253492b634e9f3970c5dc86"),
    ID: 90448,
    Name: 'Hostname1',
    Identifier: 'hostname_example1'
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("6253492b634e9f3970c5dc87"),
    ID: 66062,
    Name: 'Hostname2',
    Identifier: 'hostname_example2'
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("6253492b634e9f3970c5dc88"),
    ID: 56415,
    Name: 'Hostname3',
    Identifier: 'hostname_example3'
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("6253492b634e9f3970c5dc89"),
    ID: 84576,
    Name: 'Hostname4',
    Identifier: 'hostname_example4'
  }
]
```

```json
collection2 =
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("625350ff09043895b2c3b2d3"),
    flowSourceType: 'Unix',
    flowHostname: 'flowHostname1',
    flowIPd: '11.11.11.11'
  },
    {
    _id: ObjectId("625350ff09043895b2c3b2d3"),
    flowSourceType: 'Unix',
    flowHostname: 'hostname_example2',
    flowIPd: '12.12.12.12'
  },
    {
    _id: ObjectId("625350ff09043895b2c3b2d3"),
    flowSourceType: 'Unix',
    flowHostname: 'hostname_example3',
    flowIPd: '13.13.13.13'
  },
]
```

I need a comparison like this:

I want to search value of 'flowHostname'-collections2- in identifier in -collections1-. (I'm aiming for 2 things here, 1. to be equal, 2. contains)
In the above example, I want to get the following data.

```json
result=
[
    {
    _id: ObjectId("625350ff09043895b2c3b2d3"),
    flowSourceType: 'Unix',
    flowHostname: 'hostname_example2',
    flowIPd: '12.12.12.12'
  },
    {
    _id: ObjectId("625350ff09043895b2c3b2d3"),
    flowSourceType: 'Unix',
    flowHostname: 'hostname_example3',
    flowIPd: '13.13.13.13'
  },
]
```

It's enough for me if I get the matches somehow.

How can I do this using pymongo with python?

Answer (score 0):

Simply put the `$or` condition for equal and contains condition in the first `$match` stage of subpipeline. You can use `$limit: 1` to improve performance.

```js
db.collection2.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "collection1",
      "let": {
        f: "$flowHostname"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          "$match": {
            $expr: {
              $or: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$f",
                    "$Identifier"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $ne: [
                    {
                      "$indexOfCP": [
                        "$Identifier",
                        "$$f"
                      ]
                    },
                    -1
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $limit: 1
        }
      ],
      "as": "col1Lookup"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$col1Lookup"
  },
  {
    "$unset": "col1Lookup"
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Tmc9RwKlgMA) for your reference.